# flv.js Media error when fullscreen on Android

Tags: javascript, android, android-fullscreen, streaming-flv-video

I have a flv stream played on my android device using flv.js. Everything works fine when playing in normal mode, except when I switch to fullscreen mode, it plays for 1 second and then crash.
The FlvPlayer error log says:

```
[MSEController] > Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': The HTMLMediaElement.error attribute is not null.
```

if I log error manually when the error occurs, i.e. flvPlayer.on(flvjs.Events.ERROR, function(e)), the corresponding logs are:

```
e : MediaError
videoElement.error : MediaError {code: 3, message: "PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE: video decode error"}
```

this only occurs when in fullscreen mode, I set document.body to fullscreen

> Edit:

If I set the videoElement to fullscreen instead, the video can keep running, but it will be shrinked and keep flashing, also all elements on top of it are gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently adding a div as the video's parent can help

during fullscreen mode, the div tag needs to have the following style:

```
height/width: browser-size //without this cannot see video as overflow is hidden
overflow: hidden
transform: rotate(0.000001deg) //known bug for chrome
```